# Why is AppCompatActivity not found during gradle build?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

Adding the v7 appcompat support library to my build.gradle, I can use ActionBarActivity with no problems. But if I replace `ActionBarActivity` with `AppCompatActivity`, I get:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
:preBuild
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:preReleaseBuild
:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJava
MainActivity.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package app.test.v7.support;

// replacing ActionBarActivity with AppCompatActivity fails.
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

// replacing ActionBarActivity with AppCompatActivity fails.
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

manifest has:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="21"  />
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 21
    }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

The Android developer docs indicate that `ActionBarActivity` itself derives from `AppCompatActivity` and recommends using `AppCompatActivity` instead of (the now deprecated) `ActionBarActivity`.

Any ideas why the class cannot be found during the build?

Comment: Try moving to a newer `appcompat-v7`, like `22.2.1`. Also, since `appcompat-v7` has a transitive dependency on `support-v4`, you don't need that other `compile` statement. I also recommend that you update `compileSdkVersion` to 22 -- the general rule is that your `compileSdkVersion` should match the major version of the Android Support Package's libraries that you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @CommonsWare for the suggestions in the comments.

Updating the support library version to v22.2 in build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

sorted the problem.

Really wish this was mentioned in the Android docs (particularly since `ActionBarActivity` is now deprecated) but meh...

Answer (score 1):

With todays latest version nothing worked, until upgrading the settings.gradle gradle version fixed it (it was 2.1.3) something in gradle toolchain seems to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'